# trying to configure sources.list to read *.iso from HD

Tags: debian

My question is about apt and its configuration file sources.list
I am trying to configure sources.list to have apt including an iso file.
Searching around I have seen some suggestions and none worked here you are
the output of my last try

```
    tarcisio@casa:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
    Ign file: jessie InRelease
    Ign file: jessie Release.gpg
    Ign file: jessie Release
    Err file: jessie/main amd64 Packages
    Arquivo não encontrado
    Err file: jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
    Arquivo não encontrado
    Ign file: jessie/contrib Translation-pt_BR
    Ign file: jessie/contrib Translation-pt
    Ign file: jessie/contrib Translation-en
    Ign file: jessie/main Translation-pt_BR
    Ign file: jessie/main Translation-pt
    Ign file: jessie/main Translation-en
    W: Falhou ao buscar file:/home/tarcisio/comunicacao/linux/debian8_1/debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Arquivo não encontrado

    W: Falhou ao buscar file:/home/tarcisio/comunicacao/linux/debian8_1/debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  Arquivo não encontrado

    E: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar.
```

tarcisio@casa:/etc/apt$

Here you are the content of souces.list (the other lines are commented)

```
    deb file:/home/tarcisio/comunicacao/linux/debian8_1/debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso jessie main contrib
```

the iso file is at the directory

```
    /home/tarcisio/comunicacao/linux/debian8_1/
```

Comment: You write you have a question about `apt`, but there is no question included in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the *.iso* image first, then use *apt-cdrom* to add it to *sources.list*.

```
mount -o loop <path to iso> <path to mount point>
apt-cdrom add -m -d <path to mount point>
```

Comment: Correct, but a little more than that. `mount -o loop /path/to/iso /mount/point`

Comment: According to [*man 8 mount*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mount.8.html#contenttoc6) *THE LOOP DEVICE* section  `-o loop` is not always necessary: "*The mount command automatically creates a loop device  from  a  regular file  if  a filesystem type is not specified or the filesystem is known for libblkid*". I added the option to my answer for clarity.